# Service- how to catch exit code

Tags: c#, service, scheduling

I would like to ask about Windows services.
My service code looks like following:

```
try
{
  //...
}
catch
{
  Environment.ExitCode = 1;
}
```

After I install my service I am using a scheduling system to run service at a specific time:

```
net start MyService
//or
sc start MyService
```

So my question is, how to get information if I had exception?
Is there any command to get this information? Now I am usually running my application, then after 10 mins. stopping service. I want to do intermediate scheduling task which will tell me if in the application error has occurred. I have tried all options of "sc"- but it gives only information about service.

Contraints:

- I cannot log errors and exceptions into the event log or files
- Prefer not to change my code
- In the scheduling system I can use bat scripting (so this scipt is only place I can change something)

Comment: I think the question to consider here is why you want to execute your program as a Windows service rather than a stand-alone executable. I don't think there is any way to get the exit code for the process running as a service as your service is being run by the service control manager. If you are only running the process on demand, driven by a scheduler, consider just using a stand-alone executable.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to log errors and exceptions into the [event log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) - either a specific one you create for your service, or simply using the service as a new source for the event log.

You can use WMI to then check the event log periodically for errors.

Comment: WMI is a good solution, but I cannot do that. I want to have everything in my scheduling system.
And I cannot create event logs. I need to get exception code from service like from the winform application.

Comment: @user1021060 - Can you please update your question and explain the constraints you have? As far as I know, there shouldn't be a problem to write to the event logs.

Comment: @user1021060 - And any _other_ constraints. I can tell you to write to a file and then you tell me that's no good either. Or to use a tcp socket. Or shared memory. You need to explain _all_ constraints.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of being able to log to the event log, can you create your own "event log"? Using either a file or database table that the intermediate service polls periodically might serve your purpose.

Comment: I have updated my contraints to the question. I cant create own event log, file or database.